# hover effect with vuetify cards (nuxt)

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a vuetify card like this :

```
    <v-card class="news__card">
      <v-card-media
        :src="ip.images[0].url"
        height="150px"
        @click="onLoadNews(ip.id)"
      />
      <v-card-title primary-title @click="onLoadNews(ip.id)">
        <div class="news__card__down">
          <h3 class="subheading font-weight-medium">{{ ip.headline }}</h3>
          <div class="published">{{ ip.date }}</span> </div>
        </div>
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
```

And i want to give an effect hover the card that apply a transform on the background image. It works when i hover .v-card__media__background with this :

```
.v-card__media__background:hover {
  position: relative;
  animation: scaleMe 500ms ease-in-out 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleMe {
   100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
   }
}
```

but i would like to have this effect when hovering everywhere in the card.

Comment: Reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
.news__card:hover .v-card__media__background {
    // your animation...
}
```